# Detecting which part of a scrollview is on screen

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiscrollview

I have scroll view to which i add a variable number of uitextviews,so that the user can see each text with a swipe.Its working all fine.But i want to display a label when the user reaches the last text.I dont know how to detect whether the user has reached the last textview.
I hope im clear enough with my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of doing this is calculating the page the user is on and evaluating that ( this is to utilise page Controls) This is done easily with this:

```
int currentPage = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)+1;
```

If you simply just want to know if the user is on the last page...

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.x >= scrollView.contentSize.width-scrollView.frame.size.width)
    {
        NSLog(@"USER IS ON THE LAST PAGE");
    }
```

You would typically put this in:

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`

or:

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender;`

depending on what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks Luke,contentoffset was he thing I was overlooking